# A Theorem from My Linear Algebra Textbook

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> **Theorem** : Let $V(F)$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and let $W_1,\ldots,W_k$ be subspaces of $V$. Then the following statements are equivalent.
>
> (a) $V$ is the direct sum of $W_1,\ldots,W_k$.
>
> (b) If $B_i$ is a basis of $W_1,\ldots,W_k$, then the union $B = \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^k B_i$ is also a basis for $V$.

Although the proof of the theorem is given in the book, I am unable to digest the theorem.

**My problem:** "Equivalent statements" means that $(a) \Longleftrightarrow (b)$.

I agree that $(a)\Longrightarrow(b)$, but $(b)$ does not imply $(a)$.

**Reason:** There is no restriction about $B_i\cap B_j\ \ \forall 1\leq i, j\leq k$.

If $B_i\cap B_j\neq\emptyset$, then there exist some vectors in $W_i\oplus W_j$ that can be represented
in two ways: First, they must be represented as a linear combination of vectors of $W_i$. Second, they must be represented as a linear combination of Vectors of $W_j$.

According to the definition of direct sum, there must be a unique representation to each vector. Hence $(b)$ should not imply $(a)$.

My whole thinking is if the theorem is true we will be able assume that every vector space is direct sum of all its subspaces. That is kind of odd to accept.

Comment: The intersection of two subspaces of the same vector space is always nonempty (why?)

Comment: I dont agree .in R^3  xy plane and yz plane forms subspaces but they are not disjoint

Comment: The zero vector must be in any linear subspace.

Comment: @SeanRoberson yes  but zero vector do not belong to basis

Comment: (b) is a statement about **all** choices of bases for the two subspaces. If $W_i\cap W_2\neq\{0\}$ then **some** choices of bases will have nonempty intersection, but other choices won't.  Check that, in this situation, these other choices will make (b) false.

Comment: @Andreas you mean to say that theorem is wrong?

Comment: No, the theorem is right. I pointed out that, in the situation you were worried about (where $W_1\cap W_2\neq\{0\}$), statement (b) is false.  Since Statement (a) is also false in that situation, this is not a counterexample to the theorem.

Comment: @AndreasBlass take the example of R^3 .xy plane and yz plane form subspace .union of bases of these subspaces forms a subspace for R^3.So (b) becomes true.Now  each element is also uniquely represent as  linear combination .so(a) is also true.but intersection of bases is non empty

Comment: $\mathbb R^3$ is fine, just like any other vector space. Are you suggesting there's a problem with it? If so, try to produce a counterexample to the theorem: A vector space with two subspaces such that one of (a) and (b) is true and the other is false.

Comment: @AndreasBlass See my edited comment

Comment: In your edited comment, you assert correctly that two particular bases for $W_1$ and $W_2$ have a union that is a basis for the while space $\mathbb R^3$. Then you erroneously conclude that (b) is true. As I explained above, (b) requires this union phenomenon for **all** bases. In your example, $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\}$ is a basis for the $x$-$y$ plane and $\{(0,5,0),(0,0,1)\}$ is a basis for the $y$-$z$ plane, but their union $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,5,0),(0,0,1)\}$ is not a basis for $\mathbb R^3$ because it contains two linearly dependent vectors, $(010)$ and $0,5,0)$. So (b) is false.

Comment: I made some substantial changes to the typesetting. Please review this [convenient guide on MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). In particular, note that you don't need to put dollar signs around every part of an expression; just put them at the beginning and end. So instead of `$x$ $+$ $y$`, use `$x + y$`. Also, for bold text (which should be used sparingly!), use asterisks, not math typesetting: `like **this**`, `not like $\boldsymbol{this}$`.

Comment: @théphile33 brother i dont type them .I just use a software where i type my question .software gives me the whole the latex code which i paste here.I thought everyone does the same.It would have taken a hard time for you remembering all the codes

Comment: @AndreasBlass But in (b) it is not said that (b) must be true for all choice of basess .if i take a standard basis.then (b) is true.What kind of theorem doesn't goes well with standard basis?

Comment: As was already explained in connection with B. Goddard's answer, the standard meaning of condition (b) is that it holds for all bases. As an analogy, consider "if $n$ is even then $n+1$ is odd". This doesn't just mean that there's one even $n$ with $n=1$ odd; its meaning is for all $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement in (b) is a condition on the vector spaces and bases.  If that condition holds, then (a) is true.  You give an example where the condition doesn't hold, so it doesn't matter what (a) says.  "False implies anything" is a true statement.

To prove (b) $\rightarrow$ (a), you assume the condition holds, which will imply that the $B_i$ are disjoint.  Which will in turn imply that $V$ is the direct sum of the $W$'s.

Comment: Please read the theorem properly .the theorem says (a) and (b) are equivalent statements. Equivalent statement mean if (a) is true (b) is also true and if (b) is true ,(a) is also

Comment: Please read my answer properly.  You are mis-understanding a point of logic.  (b) says "P implies Q."  That means you get to assume Q when trying to prove (b) implies (a).

Comment: yes i get to assume (b) that is about union of bases not about their intersection.Why i should assume that their intersection is empty when there is no restriction given about it

Comment: The fact that the union is a _basis_ is a restriction.  If some intersection is non-empty, then there will be linear dependence, hence, not  a basis.

Comment: Take the example of R ^3.xy and plane and yz plane are subspaces.union of standard bases of these subspaces form a basis for R^3.You may see intersection of bases is non empty

Comment: Which means that (b) does not hold, so it's not a counterexample.  You're trying to prove that IF (b) holds THEN (a) holds.

Comment: Basis for xy plane {(1,0,0) (0,1,0}. basis for yz plane {(0,1,0) (0,0,1)}.Union of these two bses {(1,0,0)(0,1,0)(0,0,1)}.You may see union is linealy independent and is basis for R^3. Although the intersection is {(0,1,0)}.i.e., non empty.

Comment: (b) is a property of the set of subspaces.  Another basis for the $xy$-plane is $\{ (1,0,0), (1,1,0) \}.$  The union of the two bases is now 4 vectors and they are NOT linearly independent, so your example doesn't satisfy (b).  How many ways can we explain the same simple point to you?

Comment: In the theorem it is not said that (b) must hold for every choice of bases.Thats why the theorem lacks generality.In my example, i used standard basis ,What  Kind of theorem does'nt goes well with standard basis.In the theorem there must have been written that (b) must hold for every choice of basis.When it is not written there,why i should assume it myself just for the sake of shit argument that '' book cannot be wrong''.In (b) there is nothing about choice of basis,Then Why do you want to impose this condition.I suggest a condition should be given in (b) about the intersection of Bases.

Comment: It says, "If $B_i$ are bases then the union is a basis."  That means "all bases."  I don't impose the condition.  (b) IS the condition. Your example doesn't fulfill the condition as my adjustment of your example shows, because in my example the B's are bases but their union is not.

Comment: B$_{i}$ means basis of subspace W$_{i}$.it means any basis of W$_{i}$ not every basis of W$_{i}$.

Comment: No, it means every choice of bases for the W's.  "If n is odd then n^2 is odd" is an assertion about _every_ n.

Comment: Let me assume you are right. it is given that 1$\leq i\leq$k .So the number of bases is always less or equal to k .Obviously, no.

Comment: That made zero sense.  The assertion "If $1\leq i \leq k$ then $1\leq i^2 \leq k^2$ is saying something about _every_ $i$ in the range.